# Yeoman, grunt build - keeping original file names?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using the default gruntfile that is included when I scaffold out a new project.

```
copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: false,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: ['myfolder/css/**/*',


                ]
            },
        }
    }
```

I'm wanting to keep the original file names when I run the build as I keep getting b914da89.somefile.css.

What file do I need to modify to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `Gruntfile.js` to see where you are calling the `rev` task: [grunt-rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev). Removing that call should stop the modification of your file names/

Comment: How would you go about keeping the originals and have the revisioned versions?

Comment: @Andy that would make a good separate question because there are multiple ways of handling it, but a short answer without knowing your specifics is to use the copy task.